# Android : How to set TextView to top of the ImageView by programatically

Tags: android

I have created ImageView by dynamically and I want to set one TextView to top of the ImageView by programatically.

This is my code.

```
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
              R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    chatHead = new ImageView(this);
    num = new TextView(this);

    chatHead.setImageBitmap(getCircleBitmap(bm, 200));
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;
windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
```

Comment: where is the code of displaying textView?

Answer (score 0):

Use same params for textview also :

```
windowManager.addView(num, params);
```

It will show the textview on image.